# Is there a way to remove the space before citations in Microsoft Word custom bibliography styles?

Tags: xslt, openxml, citations

I'm trying to modify the Word Bibliography Style. IEEE uses brackets for superscript references, and I have already figured out how to remove those to just be a plain superscript, but I can't figure out how to stop it from inserting a space before the citation (e.g., it currently looks like "my text. <sup>1</sup>"; but I want it to look like "my text.<sup>1</sup>").

Where might I find the the code in my XSL document responsible for adding this space so that I can remove it?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how Word relates to either XSL or XSL-FO.  Can you provide more details and a code sample?

Comment: Yes, sorry! The code to create bibliography styles used in Word is created in XSL (I think - I admit I'm not an expert). Code in pastebin: https://pastebin.com/uVLhsrgh